# NAudio. Recording multichannel sound

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I'm working with Naudio, and i record multichannel sound. How can i understand what is the channel in my buffer? 
[This link](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2012/01/handling-multi-channel-audio-in-naudio.html) isn't work on my computer.
My opinion, that if buffer[] size is 2000: 1,3,5,.. is first channel, 0,2,4 elements is second channel. Is i correctly understand?

Comment: Could you please post an example of how it has done.

Comment: @Arti I cant because it was long time ago. But solution of this in Mark Heath answer of my question. I need use some marshal things to create array from bytes array, where your element size will be your bit rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how many bits per sample you have. 16 bit is the most common in which case the first two bytes form a sample for channel 1, then the next two bytes form a sample for channel 2, and so on.